# Idiom for converting false boolean return value into exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, return-value

There are some Android APIs (like [File.setWriteable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean,%20boolean%29)) which return a boolean representing success or failure, rather than throwing an exception. Assuming the surrounding code expects exceptions to be thrown on failure, what is a good idiom for converting such calls to throw an exception (and which one) if the return value is false?

Further expansion of the question: What if I have multiple such calls in succession (i.e. `setWriteable`, `setReadable`) -- what are the advantages or disadvantages of chaining them together with `&&` before throwing the exception, rather than having a `throw new IOException()` line for each one?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should provide an (ugly) example of what I'm asking for, or not...

Comment: It's not debugging only, so an assert didn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Can't you simply use Assert or throw your own exception based on the result or write a very simple wrapper?

Comment: maybe you can wrap around an aspect (AOP)?

Comment: Are aspects available by default in Android? From my googling around, it didn't look like it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (IMO, straightforward, but I suspect ugly) way would look like this:

```
if (!tmpDir.setWritable(true, false)) {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

I asked the question because it seemed like there might be a cleaner, or better way.

Comment: Hard to see what else you could have had in mind. You should construct the IOException with a message.

Comment: Well, one thing would be not having to duplicate the method name in the message.

Comment: Re "not having to duplicate the method name", I'm picturing some really heinous hack you could do using reflection.